# Possible to use python native lists to replace array altogether?

Tags: python, arrays, list, types

I come from PHP background so i am very used to arrays with key->value pairs e.g.

```
array[0] = "One"
array[1] = "Two"
array[3] = "Three"
```

Then i could `unset(array[2])` and still have keys untouched

```
array[1] -> "One"
array[3] -> "Three"
```

For all my coding experience i never used arrays without keys, because of additional flexibility they give. When started coding with Python they natively do not have arrays only [Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list).

Now lists behave differently key is assigned automatically as data is added to list

```
list = []
list.append("One")       # list[0] -> "One"
list.append("Two")       # list[1] -> "Two"
list.append("Three")     # list[2] -> "Three"
```

if i do `list.pop(1)` then list index will shift down so basically can't relay on array index anymore.

```
list[0] -> "One"
list[1] -> "Three"
```

I could have used [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module for Python or whatever module they have for this that replicate PHP functionality, however i want to first see if there is a way to achieve what i want using pure Python data types.

Lets talk about this example i am going to import a .CSV list with three columns e.g.

```
John   31   USA       516
Sam    27   UK        517
Mike   45   Germany   521
```

Now if i worked with **PHP** i'd store data as multi dimensional array

```
array[0]["name"]          = "John"
array[0]["age"]           = 31
array[0]["country"]       = "USA"
array[0]["membership_id"] = "516"

array[1]["name"]          = "Sam"
array[1]["age"]           = 27
array[1]["country"]       = "UK"
array[1]["membership_id"] = "517"

array[2]["name"]          = "Mike"
array[2]["age"]           = 45
array[2]["country"]       = "Germany"
array[2]["membership_id"] = "523"
```

or with unique `membership_id` as key which is also handy in some cases.

```
array[516]["name"]          = "John"
array[516]["age"]           = 31
array[516]["country"]       = "USA"

array[517]["name"]          = "Sam"
array[517]["age"]           = 27
array[517]["country"]       = "UK"
array[517]["membership_id"] = "517"

array[523]["name"]          = "Mike"
array[523]["age"]           = 45
array[523]["country"]       = "Germany"
```

or i could use four single dimensional arrays because in PHP if i delete key `[1]` in every array other keys will still stay [0] and `[2]` will not shift numbers.

```
name[0] = "John"
name[1] = "Sam"
name[2] = "Mike"

age[0] = 31
age[1] = 27
age[2] = 45

country[0] = "USA"
country[1] = "UK"
country[2] = "Germany"

membership_id[0] = "516"
membership_id[1] = "517"
membership_id[2] = "523"
```

1 What's the best approach to store using **Python** data types (no extra libraries) only option i come up with is to use single dimensional list or there's other ways to store this data?

```
name = []
name.append("John")
name.append("Sam")
name.append("Mike")

age = []
age.append(31)
age.append(27)
age.append(45)

country = []
country.append("USA")
country.append("UK")
country.append("Germany")

membership_id = []
membership_id.append("516")
membership_id.append("517")
membership_id.append("523")
```

2 Imagine i have list with 1000 entries, if at some point i decide to delete `John` from the list how i make this happen?

```
for n in range(0, len(membership_id) -1):
    if membership_id[n] == "516"
       name.pop(n)
       age.pop(n)
       country.pop(n)
       membership_id.pop(n)
```

above code will return `IndexError: list index out of range` so how do i do make it work?

3 At some point i want output data from lists in console as table how i do it (please no answers with fancy `zip()` function i am trying to understand basics not optimize)?

If i print line by line i am getting

```
John    Sam    Mike
31      27     45
USA     UK     Germany
516     517    521
```

format i need is

```
John   31   USA       516
Sam    27   UK        517
Mike   45   Germany   521
```

Comment: You need to focus on one question per post.

Comment: Have you looked into dictionaries?
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: It sounds like you got used to a certain quirk of PHP. When changing languages, it is time to change habits as well.

Comment: @JaxkDev totally missed that official Python documentation is so difficult to navigate and understand.

Comment: Your CSV example appears to have 4 columns - not 3.

Comment: The obvious way to do with Python is to use Pandas: read the CSV into a Pandas DataFrame then you can easily display, access, change, remove and add data however you require.

Comment: @CtrlZ yes its 4 columns, you you mentioned this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Python dictionary is ideal for this providing the names in the CSV file are unique.

Start by defining a class for the person then build a dictionary where the keys are the person's name and the associated value is an instance of your Person class.

Something like this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._name, self._age, self._country, self._number = args
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self._name:<6} {self._age} {self._country:<10} {self._number}" {self._number}"

people = dict()

with open("People.csv") as data:
    for row in data:
        person = Person(*row.split())
        people[person._name] = person

print(*people.values(), sep="\n")
```

**Output:**

```
John   31 USA        516
Sam    27 UK         517
Mike   45 Germany    521
```

Now let's assume you want to remove John. All you need to do is:

```
del people["John"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating a table in python when you need to use the key - value logic, yo need to use dictionaries. For instance:

```
table = {
  'Name' : ['Jhon', 'Sam', 'Mike'],
  'Age' : [31, 27, 45],
  'Nationality' : ['USA', 'UK', 'Germany']
  'Number' : [516, 517, 521]
}
```

As you can see, we are using the dictionary syntax and for adding several values in a column, we use list

Comment: That structure makes it cumbersome to remove everything related to, for example, "Sam"

Answer (score 0):

Define lists for each attribute

```
name = ["John", "Sam", "Mike"]
age = [31, 27, 45]
country = ["USA", "UK", "Germany"]
membership_id = ["516", "517", "523"]
```

1. You can store each person’s information as a tuple and then create a list of these tuples.

   people = [
   ("John", 31, "USA", "516"),
   ("Sam", 27, "UK", "517"),
   ("Mike", 45, "Germany", "523")
   ]
   name = people[0][0]
   age = people[0][1]

Or you can use dictionaries to store each person’s data, where keys represent attributes.

```
people = [
    {"name": "John", "age": 31, "country": "USA", "membership_id": "516"},
    {"name": "Sam", "age": 27, "country": "UK", "membership_id": "517"},
    {"name": "Mike", "age": 45, "country": "Germany", "membership_id": "523"}
]

name = people[0]["name"]  # "John"
age = people[0]["age"]
```

2 Find the index of id to be deleted in the membership_id list

```
john_index = membership_id.index("516")

# Remove the corresponding entries from all lists
name.pop(john_index)
age.pop(john_index)
country.pop(john_index)
membership_id.pop(john_index)
```

3:

```
# Printing data as a table
print("Name   Age  Country   Membership ID")
for i in range(len(name)):
    print(f"{name[i]: <6} {age[i]: <4} {country[i]: <9} {membership_id[i]}")
```

Comment: If you use a dictionary (keyed on person's name) then you only need one pop/del call to remove it. Using 4 separate lists is unmanageable especially if there's a need to add additional attributes